# How do I convert a row name to a string without using a library?

Tags: r

I want to nicely tabulate the row name and some of the values in the row, without using libraries.

I have the following

```
train <- read.csv("Regression_train.csv" )
lm.fit <-lm(mytarget ~ .,train) 
s <- summary(lm.fit) 
coef<-s$coefficients  # this is a matrix
n = nrow(coef)
v_names <-rownames(coef)
for ( i in 1:n)
{
    c_name <-paste(v_names[i])
    numchars <-nchar(c_name)
    npad <-40-numchars
    s_pad <-rep(' ',npad)
    x <- paste(c_name, s_pad," ")
    cat(x, coef[i,1], coef[i,2],coef[i,3],"\n")
}
```

This outputs incorrect data repeating the column name
I think that is because the row name is an object.
How do I convert it to a string.

I tried the following in place of paste

```
 myfunc <- function(v1) {
   deparse(substitute(v1))
 }
```

but it just output the text "v_names[i]"

I tried not using paste but there was no benefit.

[Update]
I changed myfunc to the following

myfunc <- function(v1) {
deparse(v1)
}

This works a little better in that the output contains the actual row name. Only it is in the format ""RowName"" so I need to work out how to strip out the ""

Comment: i think you want strrep instead of rep but i'm not sure what output you want

Comment: You can replace most of the clunky loop with just `sprintf("%-40s", v_names)` to get right-padded strings.  Not sure of the final result wanted though.

Comment: That is the answer.

Comment: You might want to study the code of `stats:::print.summary.lm`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I access it?

Comment: Type `stats:::print.summary.lm` and it will show the code.